# Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, r, shiny, shiny-server, nameerror

I'm trying to run a python file named `tss.py` via R in Shiny. I'm successful in running this file. But it is giving me error when I run a python file via user Interface of Shiny. I am getting no error when I run this `tss.py` in *Pycharm*. Do anyone know how can I resolve this problem?

***Files path:***

```
D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks\applications\tss.py
D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks\server.R
```

***Server.R:***

```
observeEvent(input$action,{
    py_run_file("applications/tss.py")
  })
```

***tss.py:***

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))[0])
print("Mayday! Mayday!")
```

***Error:***

```
Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
  76: <Anonymous>
```

Please don't mark this question as duplicate. I'm getting this in R not in Python. Do anyone know how can I resolve this?

Comment: there's a workaround which would probably work in your case: set `__file__` to `sys.argv[0]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre . I'm calling this `tss.py` in R Studio.

Comment: add `__file__ = sys.argv[0]` in the `tss.py` file just to test

Comment: Error is resolved. @Jean-FrançoisFabre . Can you please explain here what is `sys.argv[0]`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `__file__` isn't defined, probably a bug of the launcher. It normally happens when the package is built-in or when the program has been run throught `cx_freeze` or `py2exe`, which isn't the case here.

In your case, a workaround would be to use `sys.argv[0]` as this value. It works here because it's the main program you're running. With an auxiliary package it wouldn't work (but `__file__` maybe would :))

So I propose to add this to your `tss.py` file

```
import sys # must be done before
try:
     __file__
except NameError: 
    __file__ = sys.argv[0]
```

so if `__file__` exists, well, let it be, else define it as the filepath of the script that is running.